# Momentjs, compare a string value with number

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I have this code:

```
var result = parseInt(moment('07/07/1978', "MM/DD/YYYY").fromNow(true)) > 35
```

Is there another way using `Momentjs` that I can compare the value of `moment('07/07/1978', "MM/DD/YYYY").fromNow(true)` with a number without using parseInt (or any way to parse to number)

Comment: multiplying by one will convert a string to a number even if the resulting value is NaN `*1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `moment.diff()` to return the difference between two dates in a variety of units

> The supported measurements are years, months, weeks, days, hours, minutes, and seconds. For ease of development, the singular forms are supported as of 2.0.0. Units of measurement other than milliseconds are available in version 1.1.1.

[Difference](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/difference/)

```
const result = moment().diff(moment([1978, 7, 7]), 'years') > 35;
```